# How many instances of marathon i can deploy in a Mesos cluster?

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

I've a Mesos cluster which is having 3 master nodes & 20 agent nodes. Now i wanted to deploy "marathon" frameworks in it. I mean in multiframework Mesos cluster is there any limitations for specific number?  In-terms of Mesos or Marathon?

Is there any restriction that for one agent node , we can deploy only one Marathon framework?

Comment: We've different customers who wanted to use Mesos cluster for different frameworks like Jenkins, Kafka, Marathon.. So just wanted to know how many maximum marathon instances can be deployed on our cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation for number of frameworks.